# Provide right types for react-three-fiber group element in useRef hook

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Need to provide right type for group element. I am using useFrame hook , need access to rotation property in ref.current. Code:

```
 const cameraRef = useRef<Group<Object3DEventMap>>(null);
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
  cameraRef.current.rotation // need this property
})
 return (
    <group {...props} ref={cameraRef}>
      {children}
    </group>
  );
```

In this case I have error Group is not generic.